# Argument change after passing through several functions - Python

Tags: python

I have a strange thing in my code, I never seen that, I use a function that calls several functions built in each other and if I look at one argument which is a np.ndarray at beginning becomes a list of float see the code sample below:

in main.py I have:

```
mean_D(z,lb,ld,B,r, 'x',0)
```

in functions_traitement_multiple_trace.py:

```
def mean_D(z,lb,ld,B,r, mode,offset = 0):
...
 if mode == 'z':
        print(str(type(z)) + '1' )
        from fit_functions import intdx
        try : 
            return quad(intdx, 1e-11, 5e-6 ,
                        args=(abs(lb),abs(ld),abs(B),abs(r),offset))[0]
                        /(4e-21/(6*np.pi*0.001*abs(r)))
        except(ZeroDivisionError):
            return 10
```

in fit_functions.py:

```
@jit
def intdx(z,lb,ld,B,r,offset=0):
    print(str(type(z)) + '2')
    return Boltzman(z,abs(lb),abs(ld),abs(B))
                    *4e-21/(6*np.pi*eta_x(z,r,offset)*r)
```

And in the same file I added to the Boltzman function:

```
print(str(type(z)) + '3')
```

And the output gives me:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>1
<class 'float'>2
<class 'float'>3
<class 'float'>2
<class 'float'>3
<class 'float'>2
<class 'float'>3
<class 'float'>2
<class 'float'>3
<class 'float'>2
<class 'float'>3
<class 'float'>2
<class 'float'>3
<class 'float'>2
<class 'float'>3
<class 'float'>2
<class 'float'>3
<class 'float'>2
<class 'float'>3
<class 'float'>2
<class 'float'>3
<class 'float'>2
<class 'float'>3
<class 'float'>2
<class 'float'>3
<class 'float'>2
<class 'float'>3
<class 'float'>2
<class 'float'>3
<class 'float'>2
<class 'float'>3
<class 'float'>2
<class 'float'>3
<class 'float'>2
<class 'float'>3
<class 'float'>2
<class 'float'>3
<class 'float'>2
<class 'float'>3
<class 'float'>2
<class 'float'>3
<class 'float'>2
<class 'float'>3
```

I don't really understand what's going on here, I tried with and without numba and it returns me the same output.

The function is returning me what I need, but I want to add a for loop in the Boltmann function and I got this output:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>1
<class 'float'>2
<class 'float'>3
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-15-f859197ca9df>", line 1, in <module>
    mean_D(z,lb,ld,B,r, 'x',0)

  File "C:\Users\maxim\ownCloud\Thèse\code_python\Traitement_multiple_trace\functions_traitement_multiple_trace.py", line 121, in mean_D
    return quad(intdx, 1e-11, 5e-6 , args=(abs(lb),abs(ld),abs(B),abs(r),offset))[0]/(4e-21/(6*np.pi*0.001*abs(r)))

  File "C:\Users\maxim\Anaconda3\envs\holopy_env2\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py", line 341, in quad
    points)

  File "C:\Users\maxim\Anaconda3\envs\holopy_env2\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py", line 448, in _quad
    return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)

TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
```

Anyone already got something similar?

Comment: well you're printing the type of `z` of the `intdx` method which from your code is not clear what it gets. the only place it appears is in `quad(intdx, ...)`. what happens insode `quad`? if something, it looks as if your `intdx` function gets `abs(lb)` which is float as positional argument for `z`...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. ```scipy.integrate.quad``` compute the integral a function, here between ```1e-11``` and ```5e-6``` and it takes the first positional argument of the function so my arguments are not misordered. So what i think is happening is that the quad function do a for loop to compute the values of ```intdx```for each value of z wich is why we have alternating 2 and 3. Quad takes one value of z, pass it into intx so we have ```<class 'float'>2``` returned and  then pass it into Boltzman and we have  ```<class 'float'>3``` returned. Thanks for the help !